# Beautifulsoup parsing for CSS selector value

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have inspected down to the following element on a webpage I am trying to scrape

```
<div data-testid="home-description-text-description-text" class="Text__TextBase-sc-1cait9d-0-div Text__TextContainerBase-sc-1cait9d-1 bjqKkI DescriptionTextBody__StyledTextContainer-sc-19zdz5l-1 fObgGE">
"Spectacular views of the Columbia river and Oregon hillsides. Bring your favorite builder. Secluded and very private. Mobile homes okay. Call your favorite Realtor today."
```

I have been unable to use `page.select("data-testid")`in fact, any methods I have tried to find by "div" followed by "data-testid" have been unsuccessful. I think finding by class_ would also be unsuccessful because I believe the class is being generated by javascript and will be a different value for each page, but I am unclear on how that works.

My goal is to eventually get the text "Spectacular views of the Columbia river and Oregon hillsides. Bring your favorite builder. Secluded and very private. Mobile homes okay. Call your favorite Realtor today."

Is there a way to search based on the expected value of "home-description-text-description-text"?

Comment: view the page sources and make sure it exist

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
html = '<div data-testid="home-description-text-description-text" class="Text__TextBase-sc-1cait9d-0-div Text__TextContainerBase-sc-1cait9d-1 bjqKkI DescriptionTextBody__StyledTextContainer-sc-19zdz5l-1 fObgGE">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find_all(attrs={'data-testid': re.compile('home-description-text-description-text')})
```

Comment: are the CSS components after div that are not 'class' called attributes? I have tried to research what these are but could not quite find any beginner explanations. From what I understand you are telling soup to search for an attribute object with that key:value pair?

Comment: Yes, looking specifically for that attribute with that value. I chose to use compile but if you know the whole attribute value you don't have to. See bs4 docs the find_all() method takes these arguments find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs) Here's the docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs  You can use attrs={} with class as well, or class_=

Answer (score 0):

the selector `page.select("data-testid")` is wrong, to select tag attribute you need to wrap them using square braces `page.select("[data-testid]")`